# fast way to remove lowercase substrings from string?

Tags: python, string, numpy

What's an efficient way in Python (plain or using numpy) to remove all lowercase substring from a string `s`?

```
s = "FOObarFOOObBAR"
remove_lower(s) => "FOOFOOBAR"
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Python3.x answer:

You can make a string translation table.  Once that translation table has been created, you can use it repeatedly:

```
>>> import string
>>> table = str.maketrans('', '', string.ascii_lowercase)
>>> s = 'FOObarFOOObBAR'
>>> s.translate(table)
'FOOFOOOBAR'
```

When used this way, the first argument values map to the second argument values (where present).  If absent, it is assumed to be an identity mapping.  The third argument is the collection of values to be removed.

---

Old python2.x answer for anyone who cares:

I'd use `str.translate`. Only the delete step is performed if you pass `None` for the translation table. In this case, I pass the `ascii_lowercase` as the letters to be deleted.

```
>>> import string
>>> s = 'FOObarFOOObBAR'
>>> s.translate(None, string.ascii_lowercase)
'FOOFOOOBAR'
```

I doubt you'll find a faster way, but there's always `timeit` to compare different options if someone is motivated :).

Comment: Isn't the string module deprecated?

Comment: @DiegoHerranz -- Doesn't seem to be.  Doing a word search for "depr" on the [reference docs](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html) doesn't turn up anything.  I think that's a common rumor because most of the methods in it are simply aliases on the builtin `str` type, so they might be deprecated in the future.

Comment: I think what was deprecated were the (function versions of the) methods.  For example, in python 3.3, there are only the constants like `ascii_lowercase` and `punctuation` and classes like `Formatter` and `Template`.  There's no `rindex` or `split`.

Comment: Ahh, that's probably what it was :-)

Comment: This works only for byte strings. If the string `s` is unicode, the code above will fail with `TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`. Since strings are unicode by default in Python 3, this is not going to work in Python 3.

Answer (score 15):

My first approach would be `''.join(x for x in s if not x.islower())`

If you need speed use mgilson answer, it is a lot faster.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(x for x in 'FOOBarBaz' if not x.islower())")
3.318969964981079

>>> timeit.timeit("'FOOBarBaz'.translate(None, string.ascii_lowercase)", "import string")
0.5369198322296143

>>> timeit.timeit("re.sub('[a-z]', '', 'FOOBarBaz')", "import re")
3.631659984588623

>>> timeit.timeit("r.sub('', 'FOOBarBaz')", "import re; r = re.compile('[a-z]')")
1.9642360210418701

>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(x for x in 'FOOBarBaz' if x not in lowercase)", "lowercase = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')")
2.9605889320373535
```

Comment: +1 to both current answers, but I prefer this for two reasons.  #1 is that I use genexps all the time and so I don't have to think about the syntax.  I can never remember how `translate` and `maketrans` work.  #2 is that this approach is more robust: if the requirements change a little this is more likely to survive.

Comment: @DSM -- I had a hard time remembering how `translate` and `maketrans` work for quite a while too, but I've gotten used to it.  The annoying part is that there is no `str.maketrans` until python3.x, so you actually need to `import` string if you actually want to use a translation table.

Comment: It might be interesting to see how the performance changes on this one if you create a local `set` of lower-case characters.  Then you could test for membership in the set rather than looking at `x.islower()`.  Of course, you probably don't get anything unless you can pre-compute the set.  You don't want to do that at each iteration.  To speed this up by about 30% (based on my empirical expirience -- No actual timings), you could also use a list-comp instead of a generator expression as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

remove_lower = lambda text: re.sub('[a-z]', '', text)

s = "FOObarFOOObBAR"
s = remove_lower(s)

print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import re

s = "FOObarFOOObBAR"

remove_lower = re.sub(r'[^A-Z]',r'',s)

print(remove_lower)
```

output: FOOFOOOBAR