# 1. Delete all the lowercase alphabets from the string. input="amiT123" output="T123"

Tags: python-3.x

1. Delete all the lowercase alphabets from the string.

```
input="amiT123"
output="T123"

a="amiT123"
print(input.replace(input.lower,""))
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437589/fast-way-to-remove-lowercase-substrings-from-string

Answer (score 0):

this is quite easy solved by using regular expressions

```py
import re
input = "amiT123"
result = re.sub(r"[a-z]","",input)
print(result)
```

for more information about regular expressions: [wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Regular_Expression)

Comment: how can I separate them into uppercase, lowercase, integers?
output=[ami][T][123]

Comment: use re.findall(r"([a-z]|[A-Z][0-9]",input), this should find groups of lowercases, groups of uppercases and groups of numbers and return an list of your results for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall Can also probably with the re.split function, haven't tested yet.