# Python - Print on screen the letter in position "x"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, find

I need to find and print a letter of a word.

For example: `wOrd`

I want to print only the uppercase letter. I tried using "find()" it shows me the position of the letter but I can't show the letter "O" it shows "1".

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: `l = "wOrd"
print(l[1])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437589/fast-way-to-remove-lowercase-substrings-from-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `str.isupper` method:

```
s = "wOrd"

# print every upper-case character
print(*(char for char in s if char.isupper()))

# print every upper-case character - functional programming
print(''.join(filter(str.isupper, s)))

# print the 1st upper-case character. If none returns None
print(next((char for char in s if char.isupper()), None))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s='wOrd'

[x for x in s if x==x.upper()]

['O']

''.join(x for x in s if x==x.upper())

'O'
```

More general case:

```
s='My Name is John'

[x for x in s if x==x.upper() and x!=' ']

['M', 'N', 'J']

''.join(x for x in s if x==x.upper() and x!=' ')

'MNJ'
```

Answer (score 0):

1 is the index of the letter "O"
Once you have the index you can simply use it to print or do whatever else.

```
test = "wOrd"
print(test[1])
```

Above will print "O"